# Ubuntu 16.04 keeps asking screen password after installation of Radeon graphics driver

Tags: password

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 on dell 5559 with radeon graphics. I downloaded the package from AMD and installed it. After restarting it keeps on asking the password even after a put the right password. Once I put the password, it read and again return back and asking password.

Now I can't login the system. Anyone kindly assist, how can I open it?

Answer (score 1):

Ajay,

I experienced exactly the same but wasn't able to fix it properly so I went back to the original situation. I have a Firepro v4900 card.
I used the linux-image-4.4.0-45 to boot from;

My solution thus far was to reboot using the older kernel (43) at Grub boot screen. I uninstalled the 45 image (and thereby the amd driver) using `apt-get remove` or `synaptic`. Run a `grub update`.
Reboot and it should by default boot back in 43.
Now reinstall the 45 image. Don't touch the amd package.... when I retried I reproduced what I saw before.... trouble!

My 2ct

Alex